# Не во всех заказах проставляется город доставки

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте 1с-bitrix в админке, не всегда проставляется поле город. Поле Город автоматизировано и при заказе должен выводится тот город в котором мы заказываем. Нету никакой периодичности с которой город может выводится или с которой не выводится. Может весь день отрабатывать корректно. А в какой-то день раза 4 в заказе поле может быть пустым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле init.php есть функция которая отвечает за добавление

```html
function OnOrderAddHandler(&$ID, &$arFields) {
    if (CModule::IncludeModule('sale')) {
        $city = ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "xn--e1aofbbhkdf.xn--p1ai") ? "Архангельск" : "Северодвинск";

        $db_props = CSaleOrderPropsValue::GetList(
            array("SORT" => "ASC"),
            array("ORDER_ID" => $ID, "CODE" => "CITY")
        );
        $aProp = array();
        while ($arPROP = $db_props->Fetch()) {
            $aProp[$arPROP["ORDER_PROPS_ID"]] = $arPROP;
        }

        if (intval($aProp[12]["ID"]) > 0) {
            $r = CSaleOrderPropsValue::Update(intval($aProp[12]["ID"]), array("VALUE" => $city));
        } else {
            $arFields = array(
                "ORDER_ID" => intval($ID),
                "ORDER_PROPS_ID" => 12,
                "NAME" => "Город",
                "CODE" => "CITY",
                "VALUE" => $city,
            );

            CSaleOrderPropsValue::Add($arFields);
        }

        if (intval($aProp[25]["ID"]) > 0) {
            $r = CSaleOrderPropsValue::Update(intval($aProp[25]["ID"]), array("VALUE" => $city));
        } else {
            $arFields = array(
                "ORDER_ID" => intval($ID),
                "ORDER_PROPS_ID" => 25,
                "NAME" => "Город",
                "CODE" => "CITY",
                "VALUE" => $city,
            );

            // Логирование
            CSaleOrderPropsValue::Add($arFields);
        }
    }
}
```

Я смотрел логи. Даже когда поле город пустое у заказа в логах город присутствует.

Может быть у кого будут какие-то мысли почему так.

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза, это `&$ID`. Зачем здесь `&`?

Comment: `у заказа в логах город присутствует` - не вижу в коде запись логов.

Comment: лог присутствует в таком виде     file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitrix/php_interface/logs/order.txt', print_r($city, true));

Comment: Зачем здесь &? Вероятно это относятся к передаче параметров по ссылке в функции

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема - вы в функции обработки события `OnOrderAdd` портите входной массив $arFields. Вам в параметрах по ссылке приходит массив $arFields, а вы его меняете на какой-то левый

```
$arFields = array(
                "ORDER_ID" => intval($ID),
                "ORDER_PROPS_ID" => 12,
                "NAME" => "Город",
                "CODE" => "CITY",
                "VALUE" => $city,
            );
```

Что после этого происходит с заказом, можно только догадываться.

Comment: Программист который это писал эту функцию, сказал что можно эту часть кода убрать, но скорее всего проблема не в этом, так как по условию переменная $city всё равно будет иметь значение

Comment: Но попробовал немного видоизменить массив. Посмотрю, что выйдет из этого.

Comment: 1. Откуда у вас взялся город Новодвинск на скриншоте, если в коде только Архангельск и Северодвинск? Может, это всё же другое свойство?
2. Заполнение свойства идёт только при добавлении заказа, возможно, это свойство может портиться при обновлении заказа?

Comment: Это только часть события. Новодвинск присутствует на сайте. Да, только при добавление заказа свойство добавляется.

Comment: В sale.order.ajax в шаблоне нашел эту часть кода <input type='hidden' name='ORDER_PROP_<?= $propsByCode['EMAIL']['ID'] ?>'
                   value="<?= $propsByCode['EMAIL']['VALUE'][0] ?>" id="user_email">
            <input type='hidden' name='ORDER_PROP_<?= $propsByCode['CITY']['ID'] ?>'
                   value="<?= $arResult['ADDRESS']['city_format']?>">